# R, suppress plot from curve function

Tags: r

when using the "curve" function in R, how do you suppress/stop the plot from showing up? For example, this code always plots the curve

```
my_curve = curve(x)
```

Is there a parameter to do this or should I being using a different function? I just want the x y points as a dataframe from the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

curve() is from the graphics library and is unhandy for generating lists.

Just try using:

```
x = seq(from, to, length.out = n)
y = function(x)
```

If you stick to the curve function, the closest to a solution I know is adding `dev.off()` after the `curve()` statement!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to take advantage of the part of `curve` that you want without generating a plot.

I made a copy of the `curve` function (just type `curve` in the console); called it by a new name (`curve2`); and commented out the four lines at the end starting with `if (isTRUE(add))`. When it's called and assigned, I had a list with two vectors—`x` and `y`. No plot.