# Suppress plot window in R when saving output of plot command to variable

Tags: r, plot

I want to save the matrix of values that the `barplot()` command returns into a variable, but I don't want the plot window:

```
x <- 1:5
b <- barplot(x)  # this opens a window with the barplot
```

I have seen the answers that suggest [to create a new function from the barplot function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49037970/10061371) or [to send the graphic to a "NULL file"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24762900/10061371), but I'm not happy with either of these options.

Isn't there a way to tell a plot function not to plot, but only return its values? In the same way that you can use `type = "n"` to suppress the points and `axes = FALSE` to suppress the axes.

I was also thinking of `lm()`, which outputs the results, and `lm0 <- lm()`, which doesn't. Here, assigning the function to a variable suppresses any output to the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the `plot` argument to `barplot`

```
b <- barplot(x, plot=FALSE)
```

Comment: I knew it! I thought I had tried this and that it didn't work. Don't know what mistake I made. Thank you!